# How to make a program that automatically synchronizes

Tags: java, c++, c, vb6, batch-file

Hey i am hoping to write a program where the program automatically just copy pastes all my dad's documents from D:\office folder. So whenever I plug-in my pen-drive , the program silently copies all documents  inside my pen-drive. Also all files should be pasted to a hidden folder in the pen-drive (so it remains private) . Synchronization capability also required ...So which language should be easy and where to get started ...any idea ??.

Comment: You may also want to ask this question on superuser.com;  the answers here will be specific to programming your own solution.

Comment: I know C++, C, java, Vb6, batch etc.

Comment: Don't write code. Use something like [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp).

Comment: Delta copy is cool program , but the site dosent say its free or shareware

Comment: @Thorbjorn not till now, i will tell him when its done , it should be a surprise

Comment: For these requirement, have a look at rsync

Comment: what is rsync ? Can u be a more specific or please post a link......
(why all my comments sound as if I am a critic)

Comment: @Thorbjorn I have wondered the same ethical question instantly :-)

Comment: Sounds malicious so you'll receive no help from me.

Comment: I cant understand , what part of the program sounds malicious !!! If everything sounds malicious , then how will i improve my coding skills/knowledge ??

Comment: @subanki: This sounds like it might be bad because if you were to copy your father's documents without his permission that would be an invasion of his privacy and possibly a crime. I think that you are not trying to do this, but if you reread your question and the comments up until this one I think you will see how it might appear to be the case.

Comment: @nategose Then how can i ask for help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I infer you are on Windows. Window has a plethora of functions to manipulate files. A few functions are below.

- CopyFile Copies an existing file to a new file.
- FindFirstFile Searches a directory for a file or subdirectory name that matches a specified name.
- FindFirstFileEx  Searches a directory for a file or subdirectory name and attributes that match those that are specified.
- FindNextFile Continues a file search.
- MoveFile Moves an existing file or directory and its children.

On and on. These and many more functions are documented here.

[**File Management Functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Copy or move the files to the pen drive.

HTH

Comment: wow!! tough English for me ....u made me get my Dictionary... infer = guess, plethora = lot of (large amount)...thanks i learned something new :). By the way which programming language are you talking , is it Windows API ??

Comment: @JustBoo I am not teaing or making fun of you , but what is Anthropomorphic Personification??

Comment: Yes, Windows API...    http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnthropomorphicPersonification

Comment: Wow people please visit the above site link given by JustBoo, very inspiring and spiritual/religious site. I Bookmarked it !!

Comment: @subanki. I think it's OK to make fun of "anthromorphic personification". I think it's probably expected.

Comment: @MarkJ But i am not making Fun of it...  :(

Comment: "Anthropomorphic Personification" means presenting some abstract concept as a human being (in one form or another).  Typical example is representing Death as a hooded skeleton with a scythe.

Comment: @JustBoo  I just happen to notice that your English is better than mine. If you know any site that teaches good English then please let me know, I would love to use a higher level of English.

Comment: @subanki - Your English is quite good, IMHO.  Probably the best way to improve is to just read a lot of things in various dialects - American English, British English, South African English, etc.  Note:  I don't know if I'd describe tvtropes as inspiring or religious.  It does illustrate a lot of concepts, ideas with television situations.

Comment: @sheepsimulator Thanks for the opinion , now I have to buy a bunch of Books. Sad reading is tough job,  I guess there is no easy way out. I hope Story Books improves some English too

Comment: @subanki - Actually, I meant you should read webpages.  Like tvtropes, or whatever is fun your you.  You'll probably learn more that way.  If it isn't fun, you won't learn anything.  I'm not going to post anymore comments, cuz its completely off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that some spyin' is about to be goin' on here. :P

I'd recommend C++. Not extremely easy as .Net's tillyvally but fast, framework independent, convenient to manipulate Windows API. You wanna do advanced stealth app, you can't pick the easy way.

Comment: lol please don't make me look like a criminal trying to make/develop some malicious code. I assure its for our personal use only and no harm to anyone. So cheer up :D

Comment: Just kiddin', mate. :) Yet still serious on using C++. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Why use the clipboard when you could just use shell commands???

Maybe write an autostart batch file on your pen drive that copies files to/from your flash drive as needed.

Comment: auto-start batch file is out of the question since i format my pen-drive multiple times

Comment: Do you need to auto-detect the drive, or can you simply run a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the person who suggests this (I don't like .NET that much):

Make a C# (or VB if you must) Console app, or Forms app (if you want to get fancy).  The .NET framework will make this kind of program VERY easy and it might be fun.  Unless you want to increase your proficiency in C/C++, i would suggest NOT doing it in those languages since there is a learning curve and it is a little complex to do some simple things.

Comment: so according to yo which language would be better

Comment: C# .NET, If you really want to program it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

"Just paste" or "synchronize"?

For synchronization, unison is a good bet, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison_(file_synchronizer). For "just paste", you could code a call to a batch calling XCOPY from with the Windows Autoplay mechanism.

Sounds like a secret covert operation you're talking about, though...

Comment: lol no , its just that i want to copy the files to my pen-drive even when my friends or other non wanted people are around me , so hence it should be silent, besides i am not the one who is going to use it , its my dad :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to do a lot of work to get a less than satisfactory result.

I would suggestion you instead have a look at DropBox, which is free up to 2Gb of storage which automatically synchronizes between all registered computers, plus has a special folder which allows for web access.  Very nice.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion but i don't prefer something that is online , besides my dad's documents deserves little privacy since some of them might be office documents.

Comment: I haven't started coding since I am still not sure which language to use and I don't know Windows API , So the time being i am trying to understand what Windows API is all about

Comment: Then I would suggest a less ambitious project to warm up on.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Camel framework of Java, there you can easily run service which will for example automatically copy data from your flash disk after plug in, to folder which you specify etc.
Good tutorial how to start is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmtXkA7FlwA

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more and how will it solve OP's requirement? Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)